# Why are squirrels pruning new bayberries?

Tags: pest-control, pest-damage

Our crew has witness squirrels cutting the tops off recently planted bayberries on a number of occasions. The animals don't seem to do anything with the bark or cut tops. Why are they doing this and what could be done to prevent it (short of culling the scurry)?

[image]

Comment: Squirrels are funny little creatures. I would suggest a pretty direct method. Go buy some chicken wire and build an enclosure for the plant.

Comment: Unfortunately there are hundreds of them. The squirrels have hit maybe 10% so far.

Comment: Ah, I see okay well then I would suggest you go buy yourself some squirrel repellent.

Answer (score 2):

In wintertime in Ontario squirrels will nip the ends of maple twigs; goal is to drink the sap which is sugary at that time of year. If the nipping makes the shoots bleed sweetly then this might be one reason. You would see the nipped ends but if all the squirrels do is drink then this will not be so evident.

If this is the reason, then maybe offer them an alternative equally attractive drink that is easier to get at and they will quit nipping ends, which is more work.